# SVG element broke when updating to SVG 2, why?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I had an SVG element that was used to render lines connecting nodes in a flowchart.  At the beginning of October 2018, it suddenly stopped working in Chrome - the SVG element has 0 width and height in the DOM even though it has width and height attributes defined.

After doing some searching I found that Chrome recently updated its standards to SVG 2, however this SVG is fairly simple and I can't figure out exactly what changes caused this to happen.

Details:

The SVG is inside a regular DIV with position:relative.  The DIV appears properly and has height and width set.

The SVG has a class and used to have position:absolute.  It no longer seems to have any style and I can't edit its style through DevTools.  I'm not certain if it needed to have a style to begin with.

The SVG has a bunch of line elements in it, and nothing else.  The lines have classes and their styles don't work either.

The parent DIV does have other DIV elements in it (the nodes in the flowchart).  These elements all have position:absolute.

Neither the parent DIV nor the SVG exist when the page is opened.  They are created using Javascript.

There are no other SVG elements on the page and no use of the "use" keyword anywhere.

What part of this breaks with SVG 2 compliance?

Here is the code:

```
function appendElement(type,className,to,inner){
    if (type === 'svg' || type === 'line'){
        var el = document.createElementNS("https://www.w3.org/2000/svg", type);
        if (className !== undefined) el.setAttribute("class",className);
    } else {
        var el = document.createElement(type);
        if (className !== undefined) el.className = className;
    }
    to.appendChild(el);
    if (inner !== undefined) el.innerHTML = inner;
    return el;
}
```

The function in the flowchart class

```
setInner(){
    this.flowchart.innerHTML = '';
    this.svg = appendElement('svg','bw-flowchart-svg',this.flowchart);
    this.svg.setAttribute("width", 800);
    this.svg.setAttribute("height", 500);
    this.currentSize = [800,500];
    this.listitems = [];
    this.links = [];
    for (var i in this.obj.nodes){
        this.listitems.push(new BWBFlowchartNode(this,this.obj.nodes[i]));
    }
    for (var i in this.listitems){
        this.listitems[i].createLinks();
    }
    this.checkSize();
}
```

The createLinks function adds all of the lines and sets their X and Y values.  The lines are being added to the DOM properly.

And the style that should be applied (but neither the svg nor the lines have any styling at all)

```
.bw-flowchart-svg{
    position:absolute;
}
.bw-flowchart-line{
    stroke: rgb(0,0,0);
    stroke-width: 1;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post your code if you'd like some help.

Comment: There are lots of changes in SVG 2 all browsers are slowly implementing those changes. No browser is taking a big bang approach and Chrome's SVG 2 implementation like all other browsers is incomplete.

Comment: @MSC I added the relevant part of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line is incorrect

```
document.createElementNS("https://www.w3.org/2000/svg", type);
```

The SVG namespace is actually

```
document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", type);
```

This is true in SVG 1.1 and is unchanged in SVG 2. A namespace is not actually a URL despite looking like one.

Comment: How come it looks like a URL?

Comment: If they could've gone with anything, why choose something that will make people assume it's a URL, leading to issues like the one above? If you visit the URL `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`, not only do you find a web page with an explanation and relevant links, you'll also first be redirected to `https://www.w3.org/2000/svg`.

Comment: When they chose it https urls were rare and there was no redirect. Your hindsight is, as always 20/20.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question offended you. I just visited your blog. I didn't realize you've worked on SVG for Mozilla. I assume that means you may have contributed to the spec? In any case, I'm asking out of curiosity, not to criticize.

Comment: No offense here. I didn't start contributing to the spec till much later.